# ScalaTest hides setup failures in FreeSpec

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

when I run the following test it throws an exception directly in the description clause, befor e it reaches the in clause:

```
"when the message send actor receives a reference to an address" - {

        val unusedInThisTestActor = mock[ActorRef]
        val serviceFacade = testActor
        val keys = Array("password")
        val values =  Array("cheese")
        val addressRef = TestActorRef[ServiceEndpoint]

        val messageSender = system.actorOf(new Props(() => new MessageSendActor(unusedInThisTestActor, serviceFacade, unusedInThisTestActor)))
        messageSender ! ReferenceToAddress(addressRef, ("command", keys, values))

        "it tells the service facade to send the command to the address reference" in {
            expectMsg(SendCommandToService(addressRef,("command", keys, values)))
        }
    }
```

ScalaTest then ignores this test, rather than saying it failed which leaves everyone thinking the code is working fine. The only way to notice something went wrong is to look carefully at the output:

```
[ERROR] [06/16/2013 10:31:05.722] [main] [akka://testactorsystems/user/$$a] error while processing Create(622541251)
d7565b2b-b0a4-4af6-83c7-ed67f7bf0302akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation
    at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:170)
```

And use this to work out which tests aren't being run.

This is not very helpful, and I would prefer scala test to mark this as a failure somehow. Is that possible?

Comment: You should be getting a Suite Aborted message. How are you running your tests?

Comment: just using the menu option inside intellij - I set up the run configuration to look for all classes in my "unittests" package

Comment: OK, then this is likely a problem with IntelliJ not showing good info when a SuiteAborted event comes through. I'll try and reproduce it and if that turns out to be the case submit a bug report to the IntelliJ Scala plugin folks.

Comment: ok cool - the code lives here https://github.com/NTCoding/akkesb/tree/master/src/test/scala